# Querying in Firebase for Android isn't working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
reference = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://...........firebaseio.com/General/Dish");
dishName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        searchString = editable.toString();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("firebase",dataSnapshot.getKey());
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    s.setText(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        reference.startAt(searchString).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d("Firebase",dataSnapshot.getKey()+">>>>"+dataSnapshot.getValue()+">>>"+s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        s1.setText(searchString);
```

[image]

Why isn't Im not getting any query back from Firebase? I've used both `addValueEventListner` and `addListnerForSingleValueEvent`. Nothing is happening. "......" in Url represent my `firebase` database url. Since this is my mvp for my startup i dont want to share. And also I know `getInstances().child("..")` is also an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Distilling your code down, it becomes:

```
reference = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://...........firebaseio.com/General/Dish");
reference.startAt(searchString).addChildEventListener(...
```

Since you don't specify what to order on, Firebase will search the key in this case.

You probably want:

```
reference.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchString).addChildEventListener(...
```